# Can you choose what files Frozen-Flask freezes?

Tags: python, flask, freeze

I have an app that contains 3 apps within. One of the apps would be better if output as a static site because it is made up of static material as it is. I was able to use Frozen-Flask to create a static site application for the app on it's own, but I want to try and keep all three apps in the one WSGI app.

So my question is, is there a way to choose what files Frozen-Flask chooses to freeze so it ignores the files in app1/ and app3/ (see file structure below)?

Structure of files

Flask/

-application.py

-requirements.txt

-settings.py

-static/

-css/

-js/

-etc/

-templates/

-app1/ **with index.html, etc within.

-app2/ (app I want to make static)

-app3/

Comment: When you say "contains three apps within it" does that mean that you have three Flask applications that you are mounting together, or three Blueprints, or just three areas of your application, all using one `app` with no Blueprints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword arguments [`with_no_argument_rules`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#flask_frozen.Freezer) and [`log_url_for`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#flask_frozen.Freezer)  can be set to `False` when you create your [`Freezer`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#flask_frozen.Freezer) instance and then you can call [`register_generator`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#url-generators) to register a function or functions that will output the URLs you *want* to freeze:

```
frozen = Freezer(with_no_argument_rules=False, log_url_for=False)

@frozen.register_generator
def your_generator_here():
    yield "your", {"paths": "here"}
```

Comment: That seemed to work on making the static files. But when it calls frozen.freeze() There is an AttributeError.

..remove_extra = self.app.config['FREEZER_REMOVE_EXTRA_FILES']

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Okay, I fixed the error above. But is it okay that I am getting a MissingURLGeneratorWarning: Nothing frozen for endpoints handle_app2_routes. Which is the function under the original @app.route('my path') for app2

Comment: @MCF - worth asking another question about that with the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue :-)  Link to this one, so people have context.