# Ignoring endpoints, Frozen-Flask MissingURLGeneratorWarning?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

[Previous question about choosing only specific files to freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937727/can-you-choose-what-files-frozen-flask-freezes).

I have been working on trying to get Frozen-Flask that I want to ignore certain endpoints to keep those URLs dynamic and not static in this app. Is there a way to make a list of endpoints for Frozen-Flask to ignore.

```
#imports
app = Flask(__name__)
freezer = Freezer(with_no_argument_rules = False, log_url_for = False, app = app)
app.config['FREEZER_DESTINATION'] = 'build'

#app-bluprint1 (Want to keep this one dynamic)
@app.route('/app1/')
@app.route('/app1/<path:path>/')
def app1(path):
    ...
    return render_template(template, page = page)

#app-bluprint2
@app.route('/app2/', defaults = {'path': ''})
@app.route('/app2/<path:path>')
def app2(path):
    template = 'app2/index.html'
    page = 'home'
    if path != '':
        template = '/app2/%s.html' %path[-1]
        page = path[:-1]
    return render_template(template, page = page)

@freezer.register_generator
def handle_route():
    print "Generating Static Files Links"
    appDir = os.listdir('templates/app2')
    for filenames in appDir:
        if filenames == 'index.html':
            yield {'path': ''}
        elif filenames != 'base.html':
            yield {'path': '%s/' % filenames[:-5]}

#app-bluprint3 (Want to keep this dynamic)
@app.route('/app3/', defaults = {'path': ''})
@app.route('/app3/<path:path>')
def app3(path):
    ...
    return render_template(template, page = page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freezer.freeze()
    app.run(debug=app.config['DEBUG'], port=app.config['PORT_NUMBER'])
```

I am getting an error "MissingURLGeneratorWarning: Nothing frozen for endpoints app1, app2. However, I do not want to freeze anything for these endpoints. Is there a way to turn this warning off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple:

1. Run Python with [the `-W` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W):

   ```
   python -W ignore:'.*':flask_frozen.MissingURLGeneratorWarning
   ```
2. [Filter such warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) in your `__main__` entry:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       from warnings import simplefilter as filter_warnings
       filter_warnings('ignore', 'flask_frozen.MissingURLGeneratorWarning')
   ```

Comment: I ended up having specific arguments to pass in for either being static or dynamic. So if you chose static only the @app.route for app2 were defined, and if you chose dynamic only the routes for app1 and app3 were defined.